# Multiselect in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to use [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/benjamincanac/bootstrap-multiselect-rails) in my rails app.

In the view where I'm using it I initialize the plugin with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect();
  });
</script>
```

And it seems to work using the demo html:

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
  <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
  <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
  <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
  <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
  <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

This is great but I can't get it to work with my rails select code. Here is my attempt:

```
<%= f.fields_for :sizes do |size_fields| %>
      <%= size_fields.label :scale_id, simple_pluralize(@miniset.scales.count, 'Scale') %>
      <%= hidden_field "Set Scale", @miniset.sizes %>
      <div class = "form-inline"><%= size_fields.select :scale_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Scale.all, :id, :name, @miniset.scales.map(&:id)), {include_blank: '', :class => 'multiselect', :multiple => true} %>
<% end %></div>
```

I assume the problem is that `:class => 'multiselect', :multiple => true` doesn't call the JQuery in the same way that `<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">` does but I imagine there must be a way to make this work. Any help much much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I should add that my select IS showing up, it just isn't appearing as one of the intended smart multiselects as seen [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).

**EDIT 2:** The code for that select that the browser shows is:

```
<label for="miniset_sizes_attributes_0_scale_id">Scales</label>
      <input id="Set_Scale_#&lt;ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Size:0x007fcf644c0c08&gt;" name="Set Scale[#&lt;ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Size:0x007fcf644c0c08&gt;]" type="hidden" />
      <div class = "form-inline"><select id="miniset_sizes_attributes_0_scale_id" name="miniset[sizes_attributes][0][scale_id]"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">28mm</option>
<option value="2">54mm</option>
<option value="3">6mm</option>
<option value="4">15mm</option>
<option value="5">1/76</option></select>
      </div>
```

No sign of multiselect or multiple there. Hmm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select field options are being generated by this:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Scale.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @miniset.scales.map(&:id)})
```

The selected values (id's in your case) are not supposed to be passed as a hash, but rather as an array:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Scale.all, :id, :name, @miniset.scales.map(&:id))
```

In addition, you are passing the `class` and `multiple` attributes as part of the select options - but these aren't supported options, and the missing class is causing the jquery selector not to find your select field.  What you want is to pass them as standard *HTML options*, which requires a second hash. Here's the complete `select` builder that you should use:

```
size_fields.select :scale_id, 
                   options_from_collection_for_select(Scale.all, :id, :name, @miniset.scales.map(&:id)), 
                   {include_blank: ''}, 
                   {class: 'multiselect', multiple: true}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've swapped that code but it has had no obvious effect. Is this just an unrelated fix or ought it solve my above problem?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you expect to work and how you see that it isn't working?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is being rendered in the browser for this select field?  Also, are you sure that script is being read as part of the initial HTML (and not loaded in by AJAX)?

Comment: I have posted the HTML above. As for the second part of your question, I'm not sure. I know that I added a REQUIRE line to application.js and application.css that no doubt perform some magic.

Comment: @WorldOfProper - updated to explain what is happening and how to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for figuring that out. It now displays as intended. fantastic. Unfortunately it can't manage to build the size objects correctly any more. I'll make a separate question for that. Thanks so much.

Comment: [My new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436861/rails-multiselect-not-submitting-params-correctly)